# How do I pull content from a view into an array?

Tags: views, 6

I hav a strange task where I need to pull the content from a (well some) drupal view into an array so I can use that data later. I dont want to display contents right away, but I'll need to access it later.

I have already built the view but it was suggested that I can export the view and then create a module to grab the view data but I have no idea how to do that.

Basically what Im doing, is creating a view to pull say, 9 records of node type "blog" and on the front page, I want to pull that view, throw the results into a json array, and then do stuff with it later.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but if you're using a template to display that view, you can access an array of the view data by using the php code

```
$view->style_plugin->rendered_fields;
```

This will give you an array of everything that the view has returned.